# Content is not updating until re-deploy in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

In  `Next.js version 12` app using `getServerSideProps` I am having an issue getting content from my production CMS onto my production blog.

When I add entries to local app from CMS, it updates on my local app.
It doesn't update my production site unless I redeploy my site on production.
I'm looking for a workaround and think about those options:

- Should I try to `cache dynamic responses`like in docs?

```
 res.setHeader(
    'Cache-Control',
    'public, s-maxage=10, stale-while-revalidate=59'
  )
```

- should I switch to `getstaticprops` where I can use `revalidate` property?
- should I use 3rd party library to fix the issue?
- Could [this article](https://www.joshwcomeau.com/nextjs/refreshing-server-side-props/) be related to my Problem?

Here is a snippet of the code fetching via `getServerSideProps`:

```
 async function getAllArticles() {
   const { data } = await apolloClient.query({
    query: gql`
      query getAllArticles {
        name
      }
    `,
  });
  return data;
}
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const allArticles = await getAllArticles();

  return {
    props: {
      allArticles
    },
  };
}

const Articles: NextPage = ({allArticles}) => {
... // allArticles don't update until redeploy
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a `CMS` for getting data, using `getStaticProps` with `revalidate` will be a better approach for performance and keeping your website updated with the latest data.

```js
export const getStaticProps = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get("/api/...");
    const data = res?.data;
    
    return {
      props: {
        data,
      },
      revalidate: 20,
    }
};


function Component({ data }) {
  // render your component with the fetched data
}
```

In `dev` environment the website will fetch data instantly.

In `prod` environment the website will fetch data each 20s.

Comment: thanks for the answer. let me try

Comment: I'm glad to help.
Tell me if it works for you